# How to use custom php function to filter in ActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii2, dataprovider

I have this problem: I need to get data from database and filter them. but then I need to use custom php function to filter those filtered results using data from it.

Clasic search function in ActiveDataProvider

```
public function search($params) {

    $query = Passenger::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    // I guess my function would go like here
    Passenger::filterResultsEvenMore($dataProvider);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'passenger_id' => $this->passenger_id,
        // ...
        'version' => $this->version,
        'status' => $this->status,
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

**So my question is how to work with results of dataProvider because if I vardump the variable it looks like this and no actual data there.**

```
yii\data\ActiveDataProvider Object
(
    [query] => common\models\PassengerQuery Object
        (
            [sql] => 
            [on] => 
            [joinWith] => 
            [select] => 
            [selectOption] => 
            [distinct] => 
            [from] => 
            [groupBy] => 
            [join] => 
            [having] => 
            [union] => 
            [params] => Array()
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array()
            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array()
            [where] => Array
                (
                    [status] => 1
                )
            [limit] => 
            [offset] => 
            [orderBy] => 
            [indexBy] => 
            [emulateExecution] => 
            [modelClass] => common\models\Passenger
            [with] => 
            [asArray] => 
            [multiple] => 
            [primaryModel] => 
            [link] => 
            [via] => 
            [inverseOf] => 
        )
    [key] => 
    [db] => 
    [id] => 
    [_sort:yii\data\BaseDataProvider:private] => 
    [_pagination:yii\data\BaseDataProvider:private] => 
    [_keys:yii\data\BaseDataProvider:private] => 
    [_models:yii\data\BaseDataProvider:private] => 
    [_totalCount:yii\data\BaseDataProvider:private] => 
    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array()
    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
)
```

**UPDATE**

I need to use function like this for each record:

```
if (myFunction(table_column_1, table_column_2)) {
    result_is_ok_return_it
} else {
    do_not_return_this_record
}
```

Comment: use `$dataProvider->models` to get result.

Comment: is it that easy? I cant believe that, I had weak moment I guess, thanks man, if you write it as reply I will rate it up

Answer (score 1):

Why do you don't add your additional filters to query object used in DataProvider?
You can parse your conditions to `$query->andFilterWhere()`. If you need custom function for it just modify `$dataProvider->query` object inside function. After execute query in data provider you can only filter results by manually filter array of models stored in `$dataProvider->models`

Comment: I was thinking before `return $dataProvider;` I would do foreach () and unset models, but if that is readonly it wouldnt be possible. But how do I filter those in $query->andFilterWhere() when I need to use some custom php function that can not be done via sql ?

Answer (score 1):

To get result use [models property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html#$models-detail) or [getModels()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html#getModels()-detail)

For example,

```
$dataProvider->models;
```

**OR**

```
$dataProvider->getModels();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to produce a working example of this.
The steps are:

1. Save the page of the paginator
2. Read models from the dataProvider a page at a time.
3. Filter out each model as you wish
   4.a) If a model is filtered out, decrease the total count of the dataProvider
   4.b) If not, store the model and keys in an array.
   4.b.1) If you have read more records than the page size, exit the loop
4. Increment the page number and read another page
5. When you have either read all the records or added pagesize records to the array, exit the loop
   7.a) If records have been filtered out, set models and keys of the dataProvider (you have to change the key here to suit your model)
   7.b) If not, forget about the filtered records
6. Restore the page of your dataprovider pagination.

   ```
    $filtered_models = $filtered_keys = [];
    if( $dataProvider->pagination ) {
        $save_page = $dataProvider->pagination->getPage();
    }
    $have_been_filtered = false;
    while( true ) {
        $dataProvider->prepare(true); // force read of next page
        $non_filtered_models = $dataProvider->getModels();
        if( count($non_filtered_models) == 0 ) {
            break;
        }
        foreach( $non_filtered_models as $model ) {
            if( $model->mustBeFilteredOut() ) {
                $have_been_filtered = true;
                $dataProvider->setTotalCount( $dataProvider->getTotalCount() - 1 );
            } else {
                $filtered_models[] = $model;
                $filtered_keys[] = $model->id;
                if( $dataProvider->pagination ) {
                    if( count($filtered_models) > $dataProvider->pagination->getPageSize() ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if( $dataProvider->pagination ) {
            $dataProvider->pagination->setPage($dataProvider->pagination->getPage()+1);
        } else {
            break;
        }
        break;
    }

    if( $have_been_filtered ) {
        $dataProvider->setModels($filtered_models);
        $dataProvider->setKeys($filtered_keys);
    }
    if( $dataProvider->pagination ) {
        $dataProvider->pagination->setPage($save_page);
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think I came across a solution, (looks like it is working)

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html#setModels()-detail

After I do all my usual search stuff as described in question at beginning, I would do something like this using `setModels()` function

```
class PassengerSearch extends Passenger

    public $status; // virtual attribute not present in database table

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // ... some other rules
            [['status'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    // ...

    $filtered_models = [];
    $filter_models = false; // if you only want to filter if there is some value

    foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) {
        // if ($model->status == 1) // example
        if (!empty($this->status) && $model->status == $this->status) { // better approach, using virtual attribute $status
            $filter_models = true;
            $filtered_models[] = $model;
        }
    }

    if ($filter_models)
        $dataProvider->setModels($filtered_models);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: note: pagination does not work correctly if models are set this way